# Program doesn't print character when I enter a string

Tags: c, arrays, string, character

So I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char B,y[2];
    scanf("%c",&B);
    scanf("%s",y);
    printf("%c\n",B);
}
```

When I enter in a character for B like `S`, then a character for y like `a`, it works fine.
It prints out

```
a
S
```

However, when I enter 2 characters for y like `ab`, it prints the two characters but doesn't print out `S`.
It prints:

```
ab
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, a `char` array, defined like `y[2]` can hold only one `char` and the other space is *reserved* for terminating null for that array to behave as *string*. In other words, the max length of the *string* it can hold is only 1.

That said, as per the understanding, you should change

```
 scanf("%s",y);
```

to

```
 scanf("%1s",y);
```

to limit the input length. Otherwise, you'll experience buffer overflow which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To elaborate on adding that literal `1` in the format string, that `1` denotes the *maximum field width*.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.2, *`fscanf()`*, (*emphasis mine*)

> An input item is read from the stream, unless the specification includes an n specifier. **An
>   input item is defined as the longest sequence of input characters which does not exceed
>   any specified field width** and which is, or is a prefix of, a matching input sequence. [....]

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I'm curious: how does the '1' added affect the code?

Comment: @DanielToh It tells it to read at most 1 character into `y`, so it doesn't go out of bounds.

Comment: @DanielToh appended my answer to address that. :)

Comment: oh right, I forgot about the terminating null character, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: In that case, would changing y[2] to y[3] work just as well as the above if I'm only using the program to accept 2 characters every time?

Comment: @DanielToh sure, just change the field width to 2, also.

Comment: @SouravGhosh.: how can you always find those chapters and all? that you mention on your answer.

Comment: @SouravGhosh.: what you mean? you remmeber or ..? -_-! and chapter from where?

Comment: @coderredoc [see this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle). And some of those...well, yes, pops into mind.